# Countable Elementary Submodels $M \preccurlyeq H ( \theta) $.

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am reading through some of Kunen's material on Elementary Submodels and am a little unclear on one proof. 
Here is a part of the claim:

> Let $ \theta$ be an uncountable cardinal, and let $ M$ be a countable with $ M \preccurlyeq  H ( \theta) $. Then if $\theta > \omega_{1}$ : $ \omega_1 \in M$ and $ \omega_1 \not\subseteq M$...

I think that it is clear why $ \omega_1 \not\subseteq M$ ( given that $M$ is countable). I am unsure why $ \omega_1 \in M$. Kunen claims that

> $\omega_1 \not\subseteq M$ is clear, and $ \omega_1 \in M$ because $\omega_1$ is definable in $ H (\theta) $ ( and in $V$).

I do think that $ \omega_1$ is pretty clearly definable in $H(\theta)$ but I don't see why that implies $ \omega_1 \in M$.

Answer (score 5):

Quite generally, if $A$ is an elementary submodel of $B$, then every definable element of $B$ is in $A$.  To prove it, suppose $b$ is definable in $B$, so it's the only element of $b$ that satisfies (in $B$) a certain formula $\delta(x)$ (with just the one free variable $x$). Now the sentence $(\exists x)\,\delta(x)$ is true in $B$, so it's also true in the elementary submodel $A$.  Therefore, $A$ has an element $a$ that satisfies $\delta(x)$ in $A$.  A second use of the "elementary submodel" assumption shows that this same element $a$ also satisfies $\delta(x)$ in $B$.  But $b$ was the only element satisfying $\delta(x)$ in $B$, so we must have $a=b$.  Since $a\in A$, it follows that $b\in A$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, would the sentence $  ( \exists x ) \delta ( x) :=  \exists x(\forall a [ a : \omega \rightarrow x \Rightarrow \exists c \in x \forall \alpha \in \omega ( f ( \alpha ) \not= c) ] )$ which says that there is no onto function from $\omega $ to $x$ work? Is my use of $ \omega$ within the sentence okay? I believe $ \omega \in M$ by similar arguments and therefore we can refer to it, but i'm not sure.

Comment: BrianO is right. The proof in my answer uses in an essential way that $b$ is the *only* element of $B$ that satisfies $\delta(x)$; that fact is invoked to justify the assertion that $a=b$.  If you didn't need uniqueness, you could just take $\delta(x)$ to be $x=x$, and you'd be trying to prove that all elements of $B$ are in $A$.

Comment: My comment that "BrianO is right" referred to a comment from BrianO that was there when I started commenting but has now vanished.

Comment: (chiming in) $\omega \subseteq M$ and $\omega \in M$ for the same reason(s(, yes. However, your $\delta(x)$ doesn't require $x$ to be an ordinal, much less the least onto which $\omega$ can't be mapped. $H(\theta)$ has many witnesses for your $\delta(x)$ which are not $\omega_1$. The argument works when $\delta(x)$ defines $\omega_1$ uniquely in transitive structures.

Comment: @ Andreas Blass oops! caught me *in medias res*, while I tried to sharpen what I'd said -  hopefully I succeeded. Your comment now exhibits clairvoyance about what BrianO will soon say ;/

Comment: @BrianO I thought that might be what's going on.  So, for the benefit of future readers, the informative comments should be read in the order (1) Jmaff's comment that begins by thanking me and then asks about a certain $\delta(x)$, (2) BrianO's comment that begins "(chiming in)" and then answers Jmaff's comment, (3) my comment that begins "BrianO is right." The other three currently existing comments (including this one) are meta-comments with no mathematical content.

Answer (score 4):

Because $M \equiv H(\theta)$, $M$ contains a witness $\kappa$ to "there is a least uncountable cardinal", as that sentence is true in $H(\theta)$. Because $ M \preccurlyeq  H(\theta)$, the same is true of $\kappa$ in $H(\theta)$. Because $\omega_1 \in H(\theta)$, $H(\theta)$ knows the real "least uncountable cardinal", so $\kappa = \omega_1$.